# How to get correct phase values using numpy.fft

Tags: numpy, fft

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

n = 500
T = 10
dw = 2 * np.pi / T

t = np.linspace(0, T, n)
x = 5 * np.sin(20 * t + np.pi)  + 10 * np.sin( 40 * t + np.pi/2)

fftx = np.fft.rfft(x)
freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(n) * n * dw

amps = np.abs(fftx) * 2 /  n
angs = np.angle(fftx) 


_, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1)
ax[0].plot(t, x)
ax[1].plot(freq, amps)
ax[2].plot(freq, angs)
```

[image]

I get correct values for frequency and amplitude. But as seen from the plot the phase values are not correct. How to extract correct values for phase from fft? What exactly am I looking at in the phase plot?

I am expecting approx 3.14 and 3.14/2 for frequencies 20 and 40 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with computing the phase:

1. Your input signal is not an integer number of periods. If you replicate the signal repeatedly, you'll see you actually have a different set of frequency components than you assume when you construct the signal (the DFT can the thought of as using an infinite repetition of your signal as input). This causes the peaks to have some width to them, it also causes the phase to shift a bit.

   This issue you can fix by either windowing your signal, or creating it so it has an integer number of periods. The latter is:

   ```
   T = 3 * np.pi
   t = np.linspace(0, T, n, endpoint=False)
   ```
2. The frequencies where there is no signal (which after the fix above is all except for two frequencies), the phase will be given by noise. You can set the phase here to zero:

   ```
   angs[amps < 1] = 0
   ```

Now your plot looks like this:

[image: plot]

The phases are not as you expected, because the sine has a phase of -π/2. Repeat the experiment with `cos` instead of `sin` and you get the phases you were expecting.

Comment: Cool. That worked. > `integer number of periods` how do I get that if I don't know what signal I am analysing? Do I just add `dt = ceil(T/pi) * pi - T` to create new `T`?  or windowing is my only option in that case? (I have no idea what windowing really is).

Comment: @Pratik: Yes, if your signal is not synthetic then the only appropriate way is to window. There is a lot to read about it on the [Wikipedia page for window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function). In short, just multiply the signal with a Hann window before FFTing.

Comment: @Pratik: [Numpy has predefined window functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hamming.html#numpy.hamming).

Comment: I am trying to *cheat* 
`T_ = np.ceil(T/np.pi) * np.pi ; 
n_ = int(np.ceil(n / T * T_ )) ; 
n, T = n_, T_` 
I recalculate `n` and `T`. That appears to be working. Is it known to be a bad idea?

Comment: Hmm yeah I guess its a bad idea. what values am I going to put in for n_ - n extra values?!

Comment: @Pratik: You're making your signal length a multiple of pi, if I understand correctly. But you cannot do that if you don't know what the signal period is. And also: what if the signal period is not a multiple of your sampling period? In real-world signals you cannot pick a window length that will give you a perfect FFT. Windowing is the way to go there.